# Implementing a delegate for wordwrap in a QTreeView (Qt/PySide/PyQt)?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a tree view with a custom delegate to which I am trying to add word wrap functionality. The word wrapping is working fine, but the `sizeHint()` seems to not work, so when the text wraps, the relevant row does not expand to include it.

I thought I was taking care of it in `sizeHint()` by returning `document.size().height()`.

```
def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    text = index.model().data(index)
    document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    document.setHtml(text) 
    document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())  
    return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth(), document.size().height())
```

However, when I print out `document.size().height()` it is the same for every item.

Also, even if I manually set the height (say, to 75) just to check that things will look reasonable, the tree looks like a goldfish got shot by a bazooka (that is, it's a mess):

[image: WTF]

As you can see, the text in each row is not aligned properly in the tree.

**Similar posts**

Similar issues have come up before, but no solutions to my problem (people usually say to reimplement `sizeHint()`, and that's what I am trying):

[QTreeWidget set height of each row depending on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644416/qtreewidget-set-height-of-each-row-depending-on-content)

[QTreeView custom row height of individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859958/qtreeview-custom-row-height-of-individual-rows)

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1289-QT4-QTreeView-and-rows-with-multiple-lines

**SSCCE**

```py
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class SimpleTree(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setGeometry(500,200, 400, 300)  
        self.setUniformRowHeights(False) #optimize: but for word wrap, we don't want this!
        print "uniform heights in tree?", self.uniformRowHeights()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Task', 'Description'])
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.rootItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Sneeze'), QtGui.QStandardItem('You have been blocked up')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Tickle nose, this is a very long entry. Row should resize.'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Key first step')]
        item1 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('<b>Get a job</b>'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Do not blow it')]
        self.rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00) 
        self.rootItem.appendRow(item1)
        self.setColumnWidth(0,150)
        self.expandAll()
        self.setWordWrap(True)
        self.setItemDelegate(ItemWordWrap(self))

class ItemWordWrap(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        text = index.model().data(index) 
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument() # #print "dir(document)", dir(document)
        document.setHtml(text)       
        document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())  #keeps text from spilling over into adjacent rect
        painter.save() 
        painter.translate(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()) 
        document.drawContents(painter)  #draw the document with the painter
        painter.restore()
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        #Size should depend on number of lines wrapped
        text = index.model().data(index)
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        document.setHtml(text) 
        document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())  
        return QtCore.QSize(document.idealWidth() + 10,  document.size().height())       

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myTree = SimpleTree()
    myTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from the fact that the value for `option.rect.width()` passed into `QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint()` is -1. This is obviously bogus!

I've solved this by storing the width in the model from within the `paint()` method and accessing this from `sizeHint()`.

So in your `paint()` method add the line:

```
index.model().setData(index, option.rect.width(), QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
```

and in your `sizeHint()` method, replace `document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())` with:

```
width = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
if not width:
    width = 20
document.setTextWidth(width)
```

Comment: Wow, nice find. I didn't even consider that as a possible source of the error, it looks gorgeous now. Awesome.

Comment: That bogus width infuriated me when I found it.  In c++ you can't do the `setData()` from within the `const` infected `paint() ` method, so I gave the delegate class a `QTreeView` member variable and did `treeView->model()->setData( index, option.rect.width(), WIDTH_ROLE );`.  You could also do `const_cast<QAbstractItemModel*>( index.model() )->setData(...)`.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. sizeHint() is called before paint(), at least in PyQt6. I ended up implementing something similar to @remikz: I keep a reference to QTreeView through __init__(), and create the QTextDocument in sizeHint() with a width related to the width of the view, so that the height is properly calculated.